# Appium test report "Start" column

Tags: appium, test-reporting

I ran a test suite using Appium and got a [test report](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AIh3I.jpg). However, I could not understand the values under 'Start' column. Can someone explain what do the values under 'Start' column represent?

Note: The tests were executed at 13.04.2016, about 07:34 A.M, I could not match these information with the value stated in the report.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript stores date/times as milliseconds since The [Epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time) (midnight on 1 Jan 1970 GMT). If you wish to convert this time in human readable format visit [epoch converter](http://www.epochconverter.com/)